# How to set v-data-table groups order?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

By default, the groups initiated by the `group-by` property are sorted alphabetically, but I just want it to keep the original order or set it manually. How to configure `v-data-table` groups order ?

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="questions"
    :item-class="rowClass"
    :group-by="'group'"
    disable-pagination
    hide-default-footer
>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I'm not using `group-by` anymore, but try to `group-by="'group-position'"` with `group-position` being an integer. It should fix your issue.

Comment: @DevonDahon what does group-position mean? the field name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props) it doesn't seem to support sorting the categories per your needs. However @DevonDahon is on the right track and helped me sort my grouped content as I needed it.

But if you are here, also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533648/vuetify-datatable-changing-style-for-show-group-by-button) where one of the answers shows you how to style the category.

Just to run you through how I managed to make it work:

1. Get the data (here I stored in a data property called `notificationTypes`

```
notificationCategoryOrder: [
  "All Notifications",
  "Request",
  "Order",
  "Inventory",
  "Spend Code",
];


this.notificationTypes = resp.data.data.map((notification) => ({
  ...notification,
  position: this.notificationCategoryOrder.indexOf(notification.category),
}));
```

Then use it in the `v-data-table` like :

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  hide-default-footer
  :items="notificationTypes"
  disable-pagination
  dense
  group-by="position"
>
                <template #group.header="{ group, headers, toggle, isOpen }">
                    <td :colspan="headers.length">
                        <v-btn @click="toggle" x-small icon :ref="group">
                            <v-icon v-if="isOpen">mdi-plus</v-icon>
                            <v-icon v-else>mdi-minus</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                        <span class="mx-5 font-weight-bold">{{
                            notificationCategoryOrder[group]
                        }}</span>
                    </td>
                </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

Came out pretty clean!